# Ability to use leave inside a filter block

Tags: cil

I am writing an interpreter of CIL code, and now it is time to interpreter *leave* in a *filter* block.

How to handle it?

First idea was is that this is an invalid instruction being in a *filter* block, so such a code can't be executed. But then I looked at the standard and found strange things.

The standard ECMA-335 says that *leave* can be used (!) to exit a *filter* block:

> The leave instruction is similar to the br instruction, but the former can be used to exit a try,
> filter, or catch block whereas the ordinary branch instructions can only be used in such a
> block to transfer control within it.

At the same time:

> Control cannot be transferred out of a filter block except through the use of a throw instruction or
> executing the final endfilter instruction. In particular, it is not valid to execute a ret or leave
> instruction within a filter block.

Seems to be a contradiction.

Comment: Historically, the .NET Framework implementation pre-dates the spec, so any discrepancies are probably best resolved by seeing how existing implementations handle it.

Comment: Seems that `leave` cannot be used within `filter` block because `leave` means "stop error handling and execute instructions after error handling block". But `endfilter` means "stop executing current `filter` and go to next `filter`" and it's done to make it harder to write code that will ignore exception. One of selling points of early dotnet was it's safety

Comment: About error handling: when exception is thrown CLR looks through all nearest `filter` blocks and if none yields `true`, then goes to next `filter` in callstack until it finds one that will yield `true`. So if using `leave` will be allowed inside `filter` it will make it possible to abandon exception, which is really bad

Comment: There's also already exists [IL interpreter](https://github.com/Ourpalm/ILRuntime), so no need to reimplement it unless out of curiosity